# Execute two Insert Statements in one SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement two insert statements in one SQL Server stored procedure. I did something like this, but the second insert statement does not work. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertWrite]
   @Die nvarchar(8),
   @TSO int,
   @TSOStatus nvarchar(50);
as 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO Table1 (TSO, TSOStatus) 
    VALUES (@TSO, @TSOStatus)

    if @@rowcount > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Table2 (TSO, Die) 
        VALUES (@TSO, @Die);      

        COMMIT
    END 
    ELSE 
        ROLLBACK
END
```

Comment: What is the value of `@@rowcount`? Does the first insertion work?

Comment: You don't need that extra `commit` and `rollback` since I don't see anywhere you started the transaction.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Don't leave us in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that extra `commit` and `rollback` since I don't see anywhere you started the transaction. Not sure exactly what you are trying but the below code works just fine

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertWrite]
@Die varchar(8),
@TSO varchar(10),
@TSOStatus varchar(50)

as 

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    INSERT INTO Tab1 (TSO, TSOStatus) Values (@TSO,@TSOStatus);
 if @@rowcount > 0
    INSERT INTO Tab2 (TSO,Die) Values (@TSO, @Die);         
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this considerably:

```
create procedure dbo.InsertWrite

  @Die       nvarchar(8)  ,
  @TSO       int          ,
  @TSOStatus nvarchar(50)

as 
  set nocount    on

  begin transaction

  begin try

    insert Table1 ( TSO , TSOStatus ) values ( @TSO , @TSOStatus )
    insert Table2 ( TSO , Die       ) values ( @TSO , @Die       )
    commit transaction

  end try
  begin catch

    rollback transaction
    throw

  end catch

  return 0
go
```